# Formatting a double to 2 decimal places - compilation error

Tags: java, double, decimalformat

I'm trying to format a `double` to 2 decimal places in a program I'm writing.

I currently have

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class testd {
    double d = 1.234567;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); 
    System.out.println(df.format(d));​
}
```

Could someone tell me where it is I'm going wrong?

This line is giving me errors:

```
System.out.println(df.format(d));​
```

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `System.out.println` into a method or in block to compile. To run you need `main` method.

```
public class Test { // class name should start with capital

 public static void main(String[] arg){
  double d = 1.234567;
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); 
  System.out.println(df.format(d));​
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right, your problem is that you're not inside a method. I're trying to put your code in the class context.

Put inside a method and will work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 1.234567;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); 
        System.out.println(df.format(d));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double d = 1.234567;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    System.out.println(df.format(d));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some very odd reason i am getting an `illegal character: '\u200b'` notification on this line:

```
System.out.println(df.format(d));​
```

after i copied and pasted your code in Netbeans, but after typing the same line myself, the error doesn't appear and is working fine.

```
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

So my advice would be to re-enter the line without any copy/pasting from a website whatsoever.